# SaltStack error: State *.basic found in sls test.test is unavailable

Tags: salt-stack

I'm trying to use Salt to deploy an online tool to a new VPS. The process involves cloning a git repo and then various set-up commands - however there seems to be an issue with including other .sls files from within sub directories.

Here's a simplified version:

Master config file:

```
file_roots:
  base:
    - /srv/salt/saltstates
```

I have a a file in `/srv/salt/saltstates/test/test.sls` containing:

```
base:
  '*':
    - basic
```

The file `/srv/salt/saltstates/test/basic.sls` contains:

```
Europe/London:
    timezone.system
```

However, when I run `salt 'Minion1' state.sls test.test`, an error is returned:

```
Minion1:
----------
          ID: base
    Function: *.basic
      Result: False
     Comment: State *.basic found in sls test.test is unavailable
     Started: 
    Duration: 
     Changes:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so you've confused several things here.

First of all the contents you've put in `/srv/salt/saltstates/test/test.sls` really is what is called a `top` file and should probably be moved to `/srv/salt/saltstates/top.sls`
The `top.sls` is only needed if you want to do a highstate, but since you're trying to run `salt 'Minion1' state.sls test.test` you don't really need the `top.sls`.

Now since you have your sls file here: `/srv/salt/saltstates/test/basic.sls`, then the command you want to run is the following:

`salt 'Minion1' state.sls test.basic`

The "dot" traverses down directories.

Comment: Thanks @Utah_Dave - I was actually trying to test a proposed top file (`test.sls`).  =You're right that things became mixed up, as a top file is different to a state file.  In the end `salt 'Minion1' state.top test/test` ran the file correctly.